# ValueError - Incompatible shapes (self, other) when using tensorflow.keras.model.fit() and tensorflow.keras.metrics

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, shapes, valueerror

I am currently facing the following error:

> raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
>
> ValueError: Shapes (None, 1623) and (None, 1) are incompatible

It seems like this error is somewhat common as I found it beeing asked over and over again on various platforms. However, all the common solutions like changing from a categorical to a binary loss (or vice versa) or using [`tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical) for the labels do not work for me. So, here are the important code snippets:

The model

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model


def siamese_net(data, embedding_size=1623):
    data_input = Input(shape=data[0].shape, name='data_input')

    x = layers.Conv2D(
        filters=32,
        kernel_size=(3, 3),
        activation='relu',
        input_shape=data[0].shape
    )(data_input)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(
        filters=64,
        kernel_size=(3, 3),
        activation='relu'
    )(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
    x = layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = layers.Dense(embedding_size, activation='linear')(x)
    embeddings = layers.Lambda(lambda y: tf.math.l2_normalize(y, axis=1))(x)

    siamese_net_model = Model(inputs=data_input, outputs=embeddings)

    siamese_net_model.summary()
    plot_model(
        siamese_net_model,
        to_file='siamese_network.png',
        show_shapes=True,
        show_layer_names=True,
        expand_nested=True
    )

    return siamese_net_model
```

The main part

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from cov_net import siamese_net

# Load datasets.
train_data, train_labels,\
    valid_data, valid_labels,\
    test_data, test_labels\
    = load_omniglot_dataset()

# Make sure all the data has the right shape (num_samples, height, width, channels).
train_data = reshape_data(train_data)
valid_data = reshape_data(valid_data)
test_data = reshape_data(test_data)
tf.keras.backend.set_image_data_format("channels_last")

# Initialize generators that shuffle and batch data.
# Yielded batches contain `batch_data`, `batch_labels` with the shapes:
# `batch_data`: (batch_size, height, width, channels)
# `batch_labels`: (batch_size,)
train_generator = BatchGenerator(some_args)
valid_generator = BatchGenerator(some_args)

# Create a model.
siamese_net_model = siamese_net(data_input)

# Compile the model.
siamese_net_model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
    loss=tfa.losses.TripletHardLoss(margin=0.5)
    metrics=tf.keras.metrics.AUC()
)

# Fit the model.
history = siamese_net_model.fit(
    x=train_generator,
    validation_data=valid_generator,
    epochs=75,
    verbose=1
)
```

For the metrics I have also tried others like the `FalseNegatives`, `FalsePositives`, etc. It always gives me the error warning shown above. Now, if I use [`model.fit`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) with e.g. `accuracy` (which does not make any sense for triplet loss though) or without any [`metrics`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric), the training works just fine.

Here is the output of [`model.summary()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#summary):

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
data_input (InputLayer)      [(None, 105, 105, 1)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 103, 103, 32)      320       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 51, 51, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 49, 49, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 24, 24, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 24, 24, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 36864)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1623)              59831895  
_________________________________________________________________
lambda (Lambda)              (None, 1623)              0         
=================================================================
Total params: 59,850,711
Trainable params: 59,850,711
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

...and here the entire error message:

```
2021-01-28 15:30:52.637526: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
Epoch 1/20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\train.py", line 97, in <module>
    history = siamese_net_model.fit(
  File "user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1100, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 871, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 725, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2969, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3361, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3196, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 990, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 634, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 977, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:758 train_step
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:408 update_state
        metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
    user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py:90 decorated
        update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py:177 update_state_fn
        return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py:2075 update_state  **
        return metrics_utils.update_confusion_matrix_variables(
    user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py:354 update_confusion_matrix_variables
        y_pred.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(y_true.shape)
    user\Documents\PycharmProjects\Triplet Loss\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py:1134 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1623) and (None, 1) are incompatible


Process finished with exit code 1
```

In case it matters: The [omniglot dataset](https://github.com/brendenlake/omniglot) has 1623 classes in total. In my splits (same as the [Vinyal splits](https://github.com/jvlmdr/omniglot-eval/tree/master/splits/vinyals)) the number of different classes are as follows:

- training split: 1032
- validation split: 172
- test split: 419

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: *1623 classes in total* - I think you mean examples? Also you need to include the code for the model.

Comment: I added the model code. -- No, I actually mean 1623 classes. The [omniglot dataset](https://github.com/brendenlake/omniglot) includes 1623 different handwritten characters from 50 different alphabets. Each caracter is written by 20 different people, respectively.